# Xcode 7.3.1 not upgrading

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I had an iPhone running iOS 8 and Xcode 7.1.1. I decided to upgrade my iPhone iOS to 9.3.

I then went ahead and downloaded the latest Xcode 7.3.1 from App Store. Here's my problem. Xcode still thinks that its 7.1.1 even though 7.3.1 installation was successful. See these screenshots.

I rebooted my macbook, clicked on the "open" button from the app store and still the same thing. Macbook OS is El Captain.

What did I miss?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: what OS version are you using ? Try updating your OS !

Comment: its OS 10.11. I wouldn't have been able to download Xcode if I didn't meet the minimum requirement

Comment: You need to upgrade your MacOS to ElCaptain then only it will work, you don't need to upgrade XCode again, just update the MacOS, it should work, it let you download and install XCode, but won't work until you upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

This was unbelievable. You have to update twice! Really Apple ...

So if you run into same issue,

- reboot your macbook
- Relaunch App Store
- Search for Xcode again
- Now you will see "update" button. Click it
- It will download another 2.1GB file ontop of 4.1GB that you installed before.
- After that is done you have Xcode 7.3.1
- No need for OS upgrade. 10.11 is minimum.

[image]
[image]